# Past,past perfect with until, by

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Do we always use past tense with "until" plus time in the past, and past perfect with "by" plus time in the past?

> 1. Until last year, Anna worked as a teacher.
> 2. By last year, Anna had worked as a teacher.

Can we use past simple for "by", or past perfect for "until" in the sentences above?

Answer (score 1):

Until as a preposition means **upto the point in time or the event mentioned**.
e.g.

> Until now I have lived with my parents.
>   I was employed by a manufacturing company until 1999.

Therefore you can say-

> Until last year Anna had worked as a teacher.

**by ** is usually used to define a deadline.

e.g. Can  you finish the work by 5 o'clock.
 The sentence

> By last year, Anna had worked as a teacher.

Is not idiomatic.

Comment: Cambridge dictionary uses this sentence  with **until** with past simple-Cambridge online dictionary, grammar part-  but when it comes to **by** it uses past perfect. Moreover, it uses **before** in this case with past simple too. Logically, it should be past perfect, but I don't know why It happened there.

Comment: Can you provide the link

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/until

Comment: It says : he was a headteacher until he retired in 1980.

Comment: No one left the room until the talk ended.

Comment: Why it doesn't use past perfect before until close here? For example he had been as a headteacher until 1980. No one left the room until the talk had ended.

Comment: What about until?

Comment: Im afraid not :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are describing a continuing activity that took place until a certain point in the past (and then stopped), you should use past progressive:

> Until last year, Anna was working as a teacher.

If it is an activity that was already completed at a certain point in the past, you should use past perfect. The proposition "by" is very common in this situation:

> By the beginning of the year, Anna had bought everything she needed for school.

But there are also past perfect sentences without it:

> She found out the name of the song she had heard on the radio.

Comment: I think it couldn't be past continuous because it started at a point and continued up to the last year.

Comment: That is one of the usages of past continuous. See for example "The audience was applauding until he fell off the stage" ([here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-continuous-tense)).